# How to change '1.123.456.789' to '1.123.456,789' in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way in which I can change `1.123.456.789` to `1.123.456,789` in Python 3?

I know one way to do it is

```
d = '1.123.456.789' , type(d) is a string
print(d[::-1].replace('.',',',1)[::-1])
```

Is there any other way in which I can do it?

Comment: So you want to replace the last `.` only?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.  If you mean generally replace the last period with a comma, yours seems like a reasonable way to do it.  Why would you need a different solution?

Comment: this is very unclear man. You need to tell us the exact problem statement and the code. Also, make sure you have a specific question to ask!

Comment: you have the code. Looks clear enough to me. Come on, the question is clear, OP provided some code, and only asks for a better solution. 5 downvotes? what the heck? Do you want me to dig really _bad_ questions?

Comment: Here is a way `','.join(d.rsplit('.', 1))`.

Comment: _that one_ is bad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759998/how-to-insert-character-in-csv-cell-in-python

Comment: @Kasramvd: I always forget `rsplit`, good one.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yup, but still I think `str.partition` is slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, using `str.rpartition` to split according to the last dot, then join back omitting it, and using a different character:

```
d= '1.123.456.789'

new_d = ",".join(d.rpartition(".")[::2])

print(new_d)
```

result:

```
1.123.456,789
```

Alternate way using regex (not optimal):

```
new_d = re.sub(r"\.([^\.]+)$",r",\1",d)
```

Edit: for completeness, from Kasramvd comment, on par with `rpartition` solution:

```
new_d = ','.join(d.rsplit('.', 1))
```

(only splits once, starting from right)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to replace the last `.` within IPv4 notation string you can use `re.sub()` function:

```
import re

d= '1.123.456.789' # type(d) is a string
print(re.sub(r'\.(?=[^.]+$)', ',', d))
```

The output:

```
1.123.456,789
```

---

Another variations(which give the same result):

-- using `str.rfind()` function:

```
d = '1.123.456.789'
idx = d.rfind('.')
print(d[:idx] + ',' + d[idx + 1:])   # 1.123.456,789
```

-- using `str.rsplit()` function:

```
d = '1.123.456.789'
print(','.join(d.rsplit(".", 1)))    # 1.123.456,789
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @HuyNguyen, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Okay, another simple solution.

```
d = '1.123.456.789'
idx = len(d) - d[::-1].find('.')
print(d[:idx-1] + ',' + d[idx:])
```

Comment: or use `rfind` instead. Saves you a lot of reversing.

Comment: Thank you so much !