# How to insert character in csv cell in python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm new with python. Here is my csv file :

```
data;data;name surname; data; data
data;data;name surname; data; data
data;data;name surname; data; data
data;data;name surname; data; data
```

The thing that I want to do is to insert ";" to make name and surname 2 columns like that :

```
data;data;name;surname; data; data
data;data;name;surname; data; data
data;data;name;surname; data; data
data;data;name;surname; data; data
```

But the hard thing is sometimes there is more than one space, like that :

```
data;data;name surname surname2; data
data;data;name surname surname2 surname3; data
```

And I just want to replace the first spaces, not all like that :

```
data;data;name;surname surname2; data
data;data;name;surname surname2 surname3; data
```

Here is my code but it replaces every space:

```
def modify_rows():
    with open("result2.csv","rb") as source:
          rdr= csv.reader(source, delimiter=';')
          with open("result3.csv","wb") as result:
             wtr= csv.writer(result,delimiter=';')
                 for r in rdr:
                    rowname = r[3].replace(' ', ';')
                   wtr.writerow((r[0],r[1],rowname,r[2]))
```

Hope I can find help.

Comment: Can you give some orientations of the expected file size in columns and rows for example? The answer may be different if we are talking about big files

Comment: try `re` module of python library

Comment: I don't agree, finding the first space is way easier than regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Python's [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) to stop after a given number of matches by passing a `maxsplit` parameter. So in your case you just need to split after the first space as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';')

    for row in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=';'):
        # Skip empty lines
        if len(row) > 3:
            try:
                name, surname = row[2].split(' ', 1)
            except ValueError as e:
                # No surname
                name, surname = row[2], ''

            row[2] = name
            row.insert(3, surname)
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

So for an input with:

```
data;data;name surname1 surname2;data;data
data;data;name surname;data;data
data;data;name surname;data;data
data;data;name surname;data;data
```

You would get:

```
data;data;name;surname1 surname2;data;data
data;data;name;surname;data;data
data;data;name;surname;data;data
data;data;name;surname;data;data
```

Comment: Nice answer, I think you should include a 2-step version if the file needs to be the same, first reading into a list and then writting to the same file, including comments about the consequences of using this kind of method for big files (memory issues)

Comment: Thank you all for your help . I didn't know split() . I used it like your example but I got the error "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack" , dont know what's wrong

Comment: You either have an empty line in the csv file, or you have a row where there is only a `name` but no `surname`.

Comment: Exactly, you're right. How can I add this kind of exceptions for name but no surname ?

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot. I'm guessing I have progress to make.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to click on the tick under the up/down buttons to accept one of the answers as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> name_surname_regex = re.compile('^([^;]*;[^;]*;)([^\s]*\s[^\s]*)(.*)$')
>>> match_obj = name_surname_regex.match(data[1])
>>> for list_d in data:
        match_obj = name_surname_regex.match(list_d)
        print match_obj.group(1) + match_obj.group(2).replace(' ', ';') + match_obj.group(3)
```

trust me, if the data does not follow what you have given, you are bound to get lot of errors with the code

Comment: Over complicated and just partial answer